# Conditions for integral function to be Lipschitz

Tags: integration, lipschitz-functions

I’m looking for conditions for the function
$$F(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt$$
To be Lipschitz. I tried to take $F(x_1) - F(x_2)$ and add and subtract things but the limits make it not provable. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is bounded, and $g=a-b$ is Lipschitz, then $F$ is Lipschitz.

Edit: I only just noticed that $f$ also depends on $x$. The conditions then would be that $g$ is Lipschitz and $|f(x,t)-f(y,u)|<M|t-u|$ for some $M>0$ and all $x,y,t,u$. I don't know if this property has a name. It is not as nice as the case when $f$ depends only on $t$.

Comment: I tried to do that too but got $|F(x_1) - F(x_2)| \leq M|b(x_2) - a(x_2) + b(x_1) - a(x_1)|$ which does not lead to anything

Comment: You get $|g(x_1) + g(x_2)|$ not $-$ so not sure how

Comment: I do not think so because inside the integral you have $x$ as well. It would work if only the two limits depend on $x$

Comment: If you integrate only $f(t)$ then just take the integral and replace the limits but here the integration depends on $x$

Comment: Oops: $f(x,t)$ should also be uniformly Lipschitz in $x$.

Comment: Maybe it’s called Lipschitz with respect to the second input uniformly in the first. But then how do you prove it?

Comment: I already tried and got $|b(x_1)-a(x_1) + b(x_2) - a(x_1)| = |g(x_1) + g(x_2)|$. Could you should me your steps?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f$ is bounded, measurable, and uniformly Lipschitz in $x$, i.e. there is
$c$ such that $|f(x,t) - f(y,t)| \le c |x - y|$ for all $t$, and $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are Lipschitz and $b - a$ bounded.    We have

$$ \eqalign{|F(x) - F(y)| &= \left|\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\; dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(y,t)\; dt \right|\cr 
&\le \left| \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\; dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,t)\; dt \right| + \left|\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,t)\; dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(y,t)\; dt \right| } $$
If $G(t)$ is an antiderivative of $f(x,t)$, then $G$ is Lipschitz because $f$ is bounded, and we have
$$ \eqalign{\left| \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\; dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,t)\; dt \right| &= \left| G(b(x)) - G(a(x)) - G(b(y)) + G(a(y))\right| \cr
&\le |G(b(x)) - G(b(y))| + |G(a(y)) - G(a(x))|\cr
&\le const \cdot |x - y|} $$
and since $f$ is uniformly Lipschitz in $x$,
$$ \left|\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,t) \; dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}\; f(y,t)\; dt \right| \le |b(y) - a(y)| c |x - y| $$

Comment: There is something I can’t understand about $G$. It should be $G(x,t)$ because the integration depends on $x$ as well

Comment: Let’s say $f(x,t)=xt$ then $G(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} x t^2$

Comment: You can call it $G(x,t)$ if you wish: the point is that it's an antiderivative of the function $t \mapsto f(x,t)$ for a particular (arbitrary) $x$.

Comment: Then in the inequality you will have $G(x,b(x)) - G(y,b(y))$ instead and I’m not sure how you can proceed. If you say $G$ is Lipschitz in both variables then you need to deduce a sufficient condition for this from the maps $f$, $a$, and $b$. You can only assume properties of the three maps that we start from.

Comment: You can only assume properties of the three given maps or the maps that we compute from these, like $a-b$, $f(x,a(x))$,… but you cannot assume properties of $G$ which generally cannot be expressed in these (there are many integrals for which we don’t even write an antiderivative), and so there is a hole in the logic here.

Comment: No, I will have exactly what I wrote.  I am not using $G(y, b(y))$ at all.  I am not assuming properties of $G$: if $|f| < M$ then $$|G(x, t) - G(x, s)| =\left| \int_s^t f(x, r)\; dr \right| \le |t - s| M$$

Comment: Then we have a problem here. You will have $$\left|\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)}f(x,t)dt\right| \leq M|b(x)-a(x)| + M|b(y) - a(y)|$$ We cannot get to what you wrote above

Comment: I mean you have to get the norm inside then take the integral. You cannot remove the integral inside the norm

Comment: $$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\; dt - \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,t)\; dt = \int_{a(x)}^{a(y)} f(x,t)\; dt + \int_{b(y)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\; dt $$

Comment: Thank you so much! I got your point now. You should not have mentioned $G$ at all - this could be proven with the properties of $f$, $a$, and $b$ that you mentioned.

Comment: I still have some issues, which is about whether we have the right to add and subtract integrals like that. For each $x$, the integral $F(x)$ is only guaranteed to exist with $t$ from $a(x)$ to $b(x)$ only. Let’s say that $a < b$ at all points. If $a(x) < a(y) < b(y) < b(x)$, then for the integral with $f(y,t)$ you cannot add and remove the limit $b(x)$, since the function $t \mapsto f(y,t)$ may not even be defined from $b(y)$ to $b(x)$. Unless we could somehow define an extension to $[\min\{a(x),a(y)\}, \max\{b(x),b(y)\}$ that still lets us prove Lipschitzness, but I’m not sure how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151411/discussion-between-hello-and-robert-israel).

Comment: Like for example, $F(x) = \int_0^x \sqrt{x-t} dt$ for $x \geq 0$, which is well defined since $t$ only goes from $0$ to $x$. Let us say for example $x = 4$ and $y =5$, then the integral $\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(x,t)dt = \int_0^5 \sqrt{4-t}dt$ cannot be defined because $t$ cannot go above $4$. So the adding and subtracting of integrals cannot be done.